# Set yesterday Date in script special for Monday

Tags: linux, shell-script, date

I am writing a script a check whether exist a backup file every morning Monday to Friday. These backup file is saved in the end of everyday from Monday to Friday only named as

> 02_10_15

There is a problem that if I run my script on Monday said

> 09_10_15

It won't find out the file because the file name is

> 06_10_15

rather than yesterday

> 08_10_15

Please find my date code below,

```
#Create variables
yday=$(date --date yesterday +"%d_%m_%y")
#yday="02_10_15"
FileName=$(date --date yesterday +"%Y%m%d")
```

How can I get the date for Monday special for last Friday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unset mon
[ $(date +%u) -eq 1 ] && mon='Fri'
yday=$(date --date="last ${mon}day" +"%d_%m_%y")
```

So if it is Monday `date +%u` produce `1` so `mon` variable will set to `Fri` and *--date*'s string will be `last Friday`. Otherways it will be `last day` as `mon` remain unset(empty)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how your snippet works?

Comment: Thank you @Costas . Your idea is pretty good but your the second line didn't work for me. I have changed them a little bit. Please find the code below:
`if test $(date +"%u") -eq 1
then
   mon='Fri'
fi

yday=$(date --date="last ${mon}day" +"%d_%m_%y")`

Answer (score 1):

According to the info page, GNU `date` accepts other forms which you can use.  Here is an example:

```
FileName=$(date --date '1 day ago' +"%Y%m%d")
FileName=$(date --date 'last Friday' +"%Y%m%d")
```

However, it does not appear to support variants such as "last weekday" or "last day of week".  If your script has to run only on week-days (Monday through Friday), or take account of holidays, it will need more than a single line to accomplish this.